# Implementing Automated 2FA for API in PHP

Tags: php, api, multi-factor-authentication

I need to set up 2FA (Two-Factor Authentication) for an API built in PHP for our customers' systems to authenticte to a service on our server.  The first factor can be basic authentication over TLS ("Something I know").  The second factor must not require user interaction, such as entering a code sent via SMS, for example.  It must involve a per user tokens on the customers' systems that match the accounts associated with the basic authentication ("Something I have").

I am new to PHP programming and don't know much about this.  I have been reading about O-Auth and I have also considered solutions involving Mutual TLS.  But, I am seeking additional resources.  Can someone please direct me toward some good resources for this?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: The "*Something I have*" is a device that generates a token and user types it in, or uses the device (smartphone) to scan a barcode and perform back and forth communication. So, why do you state that it must be automated? What kind of secure 2FA would it be if user is never prompted for anything except username and password?

Comment: Thanks for your.  My apologies for taking so long to follow up.  We are deploying an API for a remote system (an intermediate system) to authenticate into our system on behalf of users of the remote system.  2FA is required for the intermediate system to access our system.  Entering a token is not an option for the remote system because there is not an individual person logging into the account on our system.  The test remote system currently authenticates automatically through the API via a username and pw. Currently considering Mutual TLS for the other factor; but, looking for other options.